# How do I set different environments in Anaconda to default to different versions of Python when I open Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have 3 environments in Anaconda. Base, which has a default Python 3.7, a separate python38 for my Python 3.8 environment and tensorflow_env for Deep Learning which requires Python 3.6. When I launch a terminal from each environment I get corresponding 3.7, 3.8 and 3.6 versions of python by running:

```
$ python
```

However, when I launch a Jupyter notebook for each environment and execute

```
$ import sys
$ sys.version
```

I get the default Python 3.7 for each session I launch. How can I get Jupyter to default to the environment Python version when I launch it? I am in Linux env. Thank you.

Comment: The default python comes from the environment jupyter is installed to. If you want your `python38` environment to be default, you need to install `notebook` into this environment and start jupyter after activating this environment.

Comment: Thank you. Used your advice and the following: https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084